# Sobject list as radio button Select Option

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension, radio-button

I am building a page where I have contact's first name and Last Name as an input field. When I enter the first and last name, and click search all the cases related to the contact should display as a list having a radio button alongside them.

I go the cases related to the contact for a `List<Case> excase{get;set;}` variable in my extension and able to show it using `apex:pageblocktable` but now the challenge is how to show this List as a radio button in my VF page:

Here is part of my VF Page where I am writing the logic:

```
<apex:pageblocksection title="Search Exsisting Cases" columns="1">
      <apex:input label="Contact First Name" value="{!first}" id="firstnameid"/>
      <apex:input label="Contact Last Name" value="{!last}" id="lastnameid"/>
       <apex:pageblockTable value="{!excase}" var="exscase" id="caselist">
            <!-- <apex:selectradio value="{!exscase.CaseNumber}"></apex:selectradio>-->
            <apex:column value="{!exscase.CaseNumber}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!exscase.Status}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!exscase.Subject}"/>
       </apex:pageblockTable>

The case should be displayed with a radio button to select
        <apex:selectRadio value="{!excase}">

    </apex:selectRadio>  

    </apex:pageblocksection>




   <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
     <apex:outputPanel id="buttons1">
        <apex:commandButton action="{!search}" value="Search" id="SearchButton"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!updatecase}"  value="Update" id="NewCase"/>
     </apex:outputPanel>
   </apex:pageBlockButtons>
 </apex:pageBlock>
```

Part of logic from my controller extension:

```
  public List<Case> excase{get;set;}

    public Pagereference search(){

    excase=[Select Id,CaseNumber,Status,Subject from Case where contact.Name=:first +' '+ last];

    return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a method in your controller that generates a selectOption list for your cases that you then pass to your page from your controller. Something like:

```
public static list<selectOption> getMyOptnsLst(){
   list<selectOption>MyOptnsLst = new list<selectOption>();
   for (Case c:excase){
     MyList.add(new selectOption(c.Id,c.Subject));
   {
   return MyOptnsLst
}
```

Once you have the above, you'd then create another Pageblock Section within a form tag that contains something like below:

```
<apex:form>
   <apex:selectRadio value="{!subject}">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!MyOptnsLst}"/>
   </apex:selectRadio><p/>
   <apex:commandButton value="Select" action="{!selectCase}" />
</apex:form>
```

Your controller would also need a method named `selectCase` and a public variable named `subject` to hold the value of the selected radio button.

You simply loop through your select list until you find the one that matches in your method.

**Edit**

To get the radio buttons to appear in separate columns, you'll need to apply some CSS along with something like this:

```
 <apex:outputLabel value="{!MyOptionsLst}" for="theSelectRadio">
 </apex:outputLabel>
```

You can also add a `<BR>` tag at the end of each line which may solve your issue.

Alternatively, you could use an apex repeat or put this all in a PageBlockTable. There are a variety of ways to do this. If you use a table, put the label in one column aligned right and the select option in another aligned left.

Comment: Thanks. Is there way to show the Radio button in one column instead of showing it all in one row?

Comment: Yes there is, use a label tag. Made some code correct there too. Apologies had them out of order.

Comment: I used it as <apex:selectRadio label="CaseList" ... > , but it still appears in one row. How to write the syntax to get in one column?

Comment: oh, I misread your comment. See my edits. Lots of options for doing this.

Comment: Which one would be the simplest one? I am not sure if I made it clear that I would like each case in separate rows appearing in a list instead of showing all cases in one single row, side by side to each other(this is by default).

Comment: Any of the above should do it. Personally, my preference would be to use a Table as I think it's the easiest to format and align and it would also match your existing PageBlockTable. But I don't know what you want the page to look like or if you want the styling that comes with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38446/discussion-between-rdvsm-and-crmprogdev).